# How do I Determine if Selected Text is Within Curly Braces in HTML Text Node

Tags: javascript

In the following HTML snippet:

```
<p>The quick brown{{ARBITRARY PLACEHOLDER TEXT}} fox</p>
```

1. The <P> element can actually be any element that can contain a text node.
2. The text within **{{}}** can be arbitrary but no markup or carriage returns or newlines.
3. The {{ARBITRARY PLACEHOLDER TEXT}} may appear in an arbitrary location within the containing element (surrounded by text or not).

Using Javascript:

1. How can I detect if the current selection (collapsed or not) is anywhere within {{ARBITRARY PLACEHOLDER TEXT}} including between the two individual open and two individual closing curly braces?
2. If the selection is within (per question #1) how can I extend the selection to include both sets of opening and closing curly braces?

Thanks in advance.

BTW- First question on SO.

Comment: By "current selection" do you mean the text selected with the mouse ?

Comment: Yes. Technically, I am working with TinyMCE, so there may be a collapsed selection in the form of a caret. But it is a simpler Javascript question if exclude TinyMCE from the scenario.

Comment: This is an interesting question, before giving you a proper answer I have to make some notes: There is not "onselecttext" event on JavaScript, so this is more an approach question, and mine would be using a mouseup event, get the selected text, test it into a regex to extract the part that has the curly braces, and then do whatever you want with the info... I do not if this will help you to achieve your goal

Comment: Where does the `ARBITRARY PLACEHOLDER TEXT` come from? Is it stored in a variable that can be tested against? Or do you need to pick out the text between `{{}}` and store it in a variable for comparison? Is the text being selected in the same element as the `ARBITRARY PLACEHOLDER TEXT` or could it be somewhere completely different?

Comment: ARBITRARY PLACEHOLDER TEXT is unknown text between{{}}. I have no way to determine ahead of time what it might be.